# Error handling misfires: Couldn't retrieve trigger: Cannot convert the column of type BYTEA to requested type long in Postgres Quartz schedular

Tags: java, postgresql, quartz-scheduler, bytea

I am new to java. In my project we are using quartz scheduler for scheduling jobs, the service is connected to Postgres earlier it was MYSQL now we are migrating to Postgres. While running the application I am getting error "Error handling misfires: Couldn't retrieve trigger: Cannot convert the column of type BYTEA to requested type long"
Please share your inputs.

I changed the Blob Datatype to Bytea in Postgres. After changing the datatype for the migration, I am facing the issue. Unable to find the data which is causing the issue.